# How does one get or create a selection or range from a dom coordinate point in javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml

Hopefully this is possible by invoking a method that gets executed by browser internal code.
Given a point x,y in dom coordinates. (that is can get relative to any node)
in an element containing text I want effectively

```
charIndex = characterUnderPoint(textNode,nodex,nodey);
```

I figure if there is some sort of facilty to do

```
range = xx.creatRange(node,x,y)
```

or

```
selection = xx.createSelection(node,x,y)
```

or

```
range.setAnchorToLocation(node,x,y)
```

etc.

I can't find anything so far that implements effectively what happens when you click to set the caret position.  all the methods seem to only take a character offset.

Mainly I want this because searching by incrementing a range through all the chars to test whether the point is in it is very slow (could be a binary search but) it should be done inside the layout engine in native code to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do this. `Range` won't help you. It's all about nodes and offsets.